# JavaFX how to overcome a website that wants to support only Chrome or other major browers

Tags: java, javafx

I'm using a web brower in my App. But the site I want to visit does not support any browsers but the following:

> Internet Exlorer 10+, Opera 23+, Mozilla Firefox 29+, Google Chrome 30+, Safari 7+

How the site gets the information of what bowser I have?

Is it possible to use one of the above browsers in my application(would be very greatful for any trace)? Or maybe I can tell the site that I use an accepted browser? 
To add - the welcome page seems to be loaded ok, but when you try to login - comes this message.

The site is [www.smartcat.ai](http://www.smartcat.ai)

Code I used - the standard from Oracle site:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.geometry.HPos;
    import javafx.geometry.VPos;
    import javafx.scene.Node;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
    import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
    import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
    import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
    import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
    import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class WebBrowserTest extends Application {
private Scene scene;
@Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    // create the scene
    stage.setTitle("Web View");
    scene = new Scene(new Browser(),750,500, Color.web("#666970"));
    stage.setScene(scene);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("webviewsample/BrowserToolbar.css");
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    launch(args);
}
}
class Browser extends Region {

final WebView browser = new WebView();
final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();

public Browser() {
    //apply the styles
    getStyleClass().add("browser");
    // load the web page
    webEngine.load("https://smartcat.ai/");
    //add the web view to the scene
    getChildren().add(browser);

}
private Node createSpacer() {
    Region spacer = new Region();
    HBox.setHgrow(spacer, Priority.ALWAYS);
    return spacer;
}

@Override protected void layoutChildren() {
    double w = getWidth();
    double h = getHeight();
    layoutInArea(browser,0,0,w,h,0, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
}

@Override protected double computePrefWidth(double height) {
    return 750;
}

@Override protected double computePrefHeight(double width) {
    return 500;
}
}
```

Comment: please show the basic code you use to display the web pages

Comment: More details are needed. I checked the page you mention with WebView class component and it's being loaded properly. If you still want you can change UserAgent by calling setUserAgent on WebEngine object inside your application

Comment: I've added more information and the code I used.

Answer (score 0):

Your application works well, can you please compile and execute your on latest java8 jdk ? So you will have updated WebEngine and your web page won't complain. The WebEngine you run currently must be old, so page detects it as old browser. Alternatively you can set webEngine.setUserAgent before webEngine.load